# How to solve Import object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto but not used protobuf compilation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an issue when I try to compile Protobuf to use TensorFlow Object Detection API

In jupyter I tried to lauch object_detection_tutorial

I got this error:

jupyter protobuf error:
[image: jupyter protobuf error]

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried to build the latest version of the api, but perhaps that's a bug? Try removing line 5 from input_reader.proto:

```
//import "object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto";
```

It looks as though it isn't used, perhaps they forgot to remove it.